# Store data into a csv file in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cube that's constantly moving in a direction and i want to store its position in terms of x, y and z co-ordinates every second in rows and columns in a excel sheet. I have a code written to collect and store data:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class fileMaker: MonoBehaviour {
    public static void putBytes(ref byte[] output, int index, float value)
    {
        //turns a float into its 4 bytes and then puts them into the output array
        //at the given index
        byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        output[index] = data[0];
        output[index + 1] = data[1];
        output[index + 2] = data[2];
        output[index + 3] = data[3];
    }
    public static void makeFile(Vector3 position)
    {
        //each float is 4 bytes.
        //3 floats in a vector 3(x,y,z) and 3x4 =12!
        byte[] output = new byte[12];
        //get bytes for each part of our lil vector3
        putBytes(ref output, 0, position.x);
        putBytes(ref output, 4, position.y);
        putBytes(ref output, 8, position.z);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/log.csv", output);
    }

    public static void loadFile()
    {
        //converts it all back into pretty print
        if (File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/log.csv"))
        {
            byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/log.csv");
            int length = input.Length;
            if (length == 12)
            {
                Vector3 ourVector3 = new Vector3();
                ourVector3.x = (float)BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 0);
                ourVector3.y = (float)BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 4);
                ourVector3.z = (float)BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 8);
                print("Position saved in file (" + Application.dataPath + "/log.csv): " + ourVector3.ToString());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

But there's 2 problems with this code.

1. The data collected is not readable. When i open the csv file i always get something like this : Ì¸AûwªAñF©Á. How do i fix this problem?

2.Another problem i face is collecting the data every second, i have a button at the side which i have to press everytime for unity to save the position of the cube. I want it to collect the cubes position every second on its own. This is what im talking about:[image: I have to press the button everytime for unity to log the cubes position on the console]
So how to do i remove this button and make unity record the position every time instead. I am very new to unity and programming.

Comment: csv files are text with commas between values. You're writing a binary file. Binary files are generally not human readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's more to your code than you're showing us, I can only ask "Why?". You're NOT saving your data as a CSV. You're pumping in byte data, and trying to read that back manually.

Here, off the top of my head, are a couple of alternatives that are a LOT less of a headache:

- Create a `Serializable` class, then either store a reference in one of your `MonoBehaviour` scripts, or use the .Net Binary Serializer.
- Store the data using Json, and then store the string, again, as either a reference in a `MonoBahviour`, or serialise it.
- Store your data in a `ScriptableObject`.

With all of the above methods, you can create a [Property Drawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html), or a [Custom Editor Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) to display your data in a grid like fashion.

**Question 1.**

Here's an example showing how to set up a ScriptableObject, store a reference to it and modify it during runtime while still in the editor:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = 0.0f;
    public TestSO so;

    public void Update ( )
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if ( timer > 1.0f )
        {
            timer -= 1.0f;
            so.Vectors.Add ( new Vector3 ( UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, 10 ), UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, 10 ), UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, 10 ) ) );
        }
    }
}

[CreateAssetMenu ( fileName = "TestSO", menuName = "Create TestSO", order = 0 )]
public class TestSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Vector3> Vectors;
}
```

To test this code:

- Go to the menu and select *Assets* > *Create* > *Create TestSO*. A ScriptableObect will be created.
- Attach the Test script to a GameObject in your hierarchy.
- Drag the previously create TestSO ScriptableObject to the object slot in the Test component.
- Click on TestSO so you see it in the hierarchy. You'll notice it has one field Vectors the you can open up with the foldout toggle.
- Run the game, and you'll notice that every second, and new Vector is added to the list.

Stop and restart the game. You'll notice that the Vectors list was saved, and is being added to on your second run of the game. The ScriptableObject data, while in the Unity Editor, is being automatically serialised.

**Question 2.**

As for you second question, that's a whole other kettle of fish. What you're looking for are scripts that will run in Edit mode. Specifically, you decorate methods within your scripts with [ExecuteInEditMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html). You'll then want to create a recurring Coroutine that checks your cubes position, and saves the data, or, my preference would be to using the System.Threading.Tasks namespace. You could setup a method, for example:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
public async void PollCubePosition ( )
{
    if ( pollCube ) return;
    pollCube = true;

    do
    {
        // Read cube data and perform whatever functions you want here..

        // Wait 1 seconds.
        await Task.Delay ( 1000 );
    } while ( pollCube );
}
#endif
```

You just need to set `pollCube` to false when you've finished editing, because this will run indefinitely. (You could put some safeguards in there as well to set pollCube  to false after a certain time as well, in case you forget).

Comment: This is actually not my code, i found it in a forum: https://forum.unity.com/threads/logging-player-position.80908/#post-519582  .

Comment: im think ill use a custom editor window like you mentioned, but how do i store the data as a scriptable object?

Comment: I dont need to have a grid in unity using the custom editor, my main goal is just extract and store the positional data into the csv file. I just want to know what code to use in order to do that.

Comment: I updated that answer to address ScriptableObject serialisation. This doesn't answer specifically your request to read and write to a csv file, though I don't think that's what your actual intentions/final requirement is, if I may presume. Trust me when I say it doesn't get much easier or robust as this, without having to write a custom csv (de)serialiser.